# "Snag (a chance, an opportunity, etc.) for "seize/snatch" in AE

Tags: idioms, american-english, vocabulary, word-usage

Does "snag" have any currency in modern day AE to say "snatch (or seize) (a chance, an occasion, etc.), and can it be used just about interchangeably with the latter? Or, is there a subtle difference to it?

Consider these sourced examples:

> We snagged the chance to ask him a few questions. [source](http://www.marieclaire.com/sitemap/section_46210)
>
> Talking about the program, she happily acknowledges that she snagged the chance of a lifetime. [source](http://www.bravamagazine.com/BRAVAMagazine/Profiles/RachelFrank.aspx)
>
> Photographer David Goldman thought he had snagged the opportunity of a lifetime.
>   [source](http://articles.latimes.com/1998/oct/04/local/me-29210)
>
> I had snagged the opportunity to design costumes for an Off-Broadway show.
>   [source](http://www.cla.purdue.edu/theatre/documents/ANNA%20IN%20THE%20TROPICS%20playbill.pdf)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is not an uncommon construction.

Answer (score 1):

In referring to catching a husband, one would say "I snagged an MD, Phd!" That same sentence would be wrong with seized or snatched.